# Socket.IO chat example made with Node.JS is not working on Azure in "transport mode"=websocket

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io

Following issue:
I have Azure free tier and created a web app based on Node.JS 12 LTS runtime. The web app source code is the Socket.IO chat example which can be found [here](https://github.com/socketio/chat-example).

The chat example works perfectly on my local machine. -> Socket.IO uses the `transport=websocket`.

I deployed the same source code via Visual Studio Code to Azure. There I configured under General settings -> Web sockets: On.

On the first glance the chat example works. But when I switch to the development console in Chrome I get following message:

> socket.io-1.2.0.js:2 WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://*.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=tWzTFtk3ABb3jeCWAAAE'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   503

I found something [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) under WebSockets Connection Limits fits to my error message. But I testet the chat example with less than 5 clients. :-/  I also started a remote debug seassion where I inspect the Socket.IO instance and there where always less than 5 clients connected to the server.

What I want: A Socket.IO communication which is using `transport=websocket` and runs in Azure (under free tier).

Comment: Same here i've been struggling for days now.. nothing seems to work i alway get 503's with socket io on azure